# How to get the text size of a UILabel if the number of line is fixed?

Tags: ios, text, uilabel

I have to determine that if a UILabel has text that fits the size. I can use boudingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context but I cannot explicitly set the number of line. In the deprecated method, I can only set line break mode.
Does any one know how to get the size of some text in a label if the number of line is determined (say label.numberofline = 2)?

Comment: Size of text has no dependence on the number of lines in the bounding UILabel

Comment: But the UILabel will use numberofline to truncate the text.

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : label.font}
                   context:nil];
CGSize size = frame.size;
NSLog(@"Size of frame %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
```

Comment: It is not accurate when the numberofline of UILabel is more than 1. If the height of a label is large enough it can contain 3 lines but if the numberofline is set to 2, the text will still be truncated and your code cannot tell it.